# Using requests and HTTPBasicAuth to retrieve a zip file from a password-protected site

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use requests and HTTPBasicAuth to retrieve data from a website that requires a username/password, and while I have tried to follow the usual advice in getting this to work, it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.

Specifically, I am trying to download data from Columbia's SEDAC website as follows.

```
url = "http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/downloads/data/sdei/sdei-global-nnual-avg-pm2-5-modis-misr-seawifs-aod-1998-2012/global-annual-avg-pm2-5-modis-misr-seawifs-aod-2001-2010-geotiff.zip"
username = '<name>'
password = '<password>'
r = requests.get(url, auth=HttpBasicAuth(username, password))
```

Now, as it happens, if I look at the content of the request, I find that it gives me an html file, not the .zip file that I desire. Something like:

r.content

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n    <title>Earthdata Login</title>\n
```

and so on. It seems that I can't actually automate the getting of the actual zip file I desire. I am using Python 3.5.2 and would be much obliged for any help!

Best,

Matt

Comment: Are you sure that target web-app uses `BasicAuthentication`?

Answer (score 0):

The url you are trying to access is not protected by http basic auth. You need to submit the form with the credentials.